# Create hierarchy from recordset

Tags: list, vb6, hierarchy, adodb, recordset

I have the following problem:
I have to sort the data of a recordset with a hierarchy.

This is the data as it comes from the database.

[image]

You see there are two columns, POS and PARENT.
These values must be related to each other.
If PARENT is 0, then the value in the new sort simply gets a consecutive number. In this case 1-3.

The other values each get a new consecutive number, based on the parent.

[image]

I'm pretty sure I could solve this problem in C#, but in this case VB6 is mandatory. Unfortunately I have extreme problems solving the problem with VB6.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a linked list exercise. You can create a clsListItem class that has a FirstChild object and a NextItem object:

```
Public Position As Integer
Public Hierarchy As String
Public FirstChild As clsListItem
Public NextItem As clsListItem
```

As you go down the list, you create a new object and look for its parent. You then check if the FirstChild of the parent exists or not. If it doesn't, you Set the object as the FirstChild, otherwise you navigate through children objects using NextItem until NextItem is Nothing. You then Set the object as NextItem:

```
Public Sub Sort(ByVal p_sList As String)
    Dim arrLines
    Dim arrFields
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim objItem As clsListItem
    Dim objParent As clsListItem
    Dim objChild As clsListItem
    Dim iPosition As Integer
    Dim iParent As Integer
    Dim iParentIndex As Integer
    Dim iChildIndex As Integer

    ' Split values into lines
    arrLines = Split(p_sList, vbCrLf)

    ' Initialize Parent Index
    iParentIndex = 1

    For iCounter = 1 To UBound(arrLines) + 1

        arrFields = Split(arrLines(iCounter - 1), ",")

        iPosition = arrFields(0)
        iParent = arrFields(1)

        ' Get Item
        Set objItem = GetItem(iPosition)

        If iParent = 0 Then

            ' This is a top-level item
            objItem.Hierarchy = iParentIndex
            iParentIndex = iParentIndex + 1

        Else

            ' Get Parent
            Set objParent = GetItem(iParent)

            ' Initialize Child Index
            iChildIndex = 1

            If objParent.FirstChild Is Nothing Then
                ' We are the first child
                Set objParent.FirstChild = objItem
            Else

                ' Find last child
                Set objChild = objParent.FirstChild
                iChildIndex = iChildIndex + 1

                Do While Not objChild.NextItem Is Nothing
                    Set objChild = objChild.NextItem
                    iChildIndex = iChildIndex + 1
                Loop

                Set objChild.NextItem = objItem

            End If

            objItem.Hierarchy = objParent.Hierarchy & "." & iChildIndex

        End If

    Next

    Dim sMessage As String

    For iCounter = 1 To colListItems.Count
        Set objItem = colListItems.item(iCounter)
        With objItem
            sMessage = sMessage & .Position & ": " & .Hierarchy & vbCrLf
        End With
    Next

    MsgBox sMessage

End Sub
```

That should organize all your data into objects with the desired hierarchy.

Helper function to Get/Create items:

```
Public Function GetItem(ByVal p_iPosition As Integer) As clsListItem
    Dim objItem As clsListItem

    On Error GoTo ItemNotFound

    Set objItem = colListItems.item("P" & p_iPosition)

    GoTo ReturnItem

ItemNotFound:

    Set objItem = New clsListItem
    objItem.Position = p_iPosition

    colListItems.Add objItem, "P" & p_iPosition

ReturnItem:
    Set GetItem = objItem
End Function
```

Finally, the code I used to create the table of values you have (double-check it, could be typo):

```
Private Function AddPair(ByVal p_sList As String, ByVal p_iPos As Integer, ByVal p_iParent As Integer) As String
    Dim sReturn As String

    sReturn = p_sList

    If sReturn <> "" Then sReturn = sReturn & vbCrLf

    sReturn = sReturn & p_iPos & "," & p_iParent

    AddPair = sReturn


End Function
```

and this is the main subroutine:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim list As String

    list = AddPair(list, 1, 0)
    list = AddPair(list, 13, 0)
    list = AddPair(list, 16, 0)
    list = AddPair(list, 2, 1)
    list = AddPair(list, 12, 1)
    list = AddPair(list, 3, 2)
    list = AddPair(list, 4, 2)
    list = AddPair(list, 5, 2)
    list = AddPair(list, 6, 2)
    list = AddPair(list, 7, 2)
    list = AddPair(list, 8, 7)
    list = AddPair(list, 11, 7)
    list = AddPair(list, 9, 8)
    list = AddPair(list, 10, 8)
    list = AddPair(list, 14, 13)
    list = AddPair(list, 15, 13)
    list = AddPair(list, 17, 16)
    list = AddPair(list, 18, 16)

    Sort (list)

End Sub
```